# github repository settings: permissions & development model

Tags: github

[There are two popular models of collaborative development on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests#a-quick-note-on-collaborative-development-models):

1. Fork & pull
2. Shared repository model.

How to check which model the given repository uses? How to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't something that's formally included a GitHub repository's settings. It's something that is determined by the repository's permissions, and it's simply a recognition of some common conventions.

Do you have push access? Then (for you) the repository is effectively "shared":

> The *shared repository model* is more prevalent with small teams and organizations collaborating on private projects. Everyone is granted push access to a single shared repository and topic branches are used to isolate changes.
>
> Pull requests are especially useful in the *fork & pull model* because they provide a way to notify project maintainers about changes in your fork. However, they're also useful in the *shared repository model* where they're used to initiate code review and general discussion about a set of changes before being merged into a mainline branch.

If not, then it's effectively "fork & pull" (again, for you):

> The *fork & pull model* lets anyone fork an existing repository and push changes to their personal fork without requiring access be granted to the source repository. The changes must then be pulled into the source repository by the project maintainer. This model reduces the amount of friction for new contributors and is popular with open source projects because it allows people to work independently without upfront coordination.

Note that in both cases I said "for you". It is possible and common to grant a core group of committers push access ("shared model"), while still accepting pull requests from outsiders ("fork & pull"). If this *were* a setting, it wouldn't be on the repository. It would be a setting for each user who may have access to the repository.

And there are many other possible models, one obvious one being a private repository where *certain users* may fork the repository and submit pull requests. All other users wouldn't have any access to such a repository at all.